# Scala: how to upsert field value in Monocle

Tags: scala, monocle-scala

Given the [JsonExample](https://github.com/julien-truffaut/Monocle/blob/master/example/src/test/scala/monocle/JsonExample.scala) in the monocle project, I would like to create a lens where a set call will either replace a value in a key/value pair, or create the key/value pair if it doesnt already exist.

However this seems to represented with either an index (which can compose type safe) or an at, which does not type safe

```
//for replacing:
(jsObject composeOptional index("age") composePrism jsNumber).set(45)

//for creating:
(jsObject composeLens at("age")).set(JsNumber(45)) <- will accept any old json
```

Is what I am after possible?
Also could I extend it, such that if age was nested in another JsObject, for example:

```
val n = (jsObject composeOptional index("nested") composePrism 
jsObject composeOptional index("age") composePrism jsNumber).set(45)
```

Where the key/value pair for "nested" didnt yet exist, that it would create the object at nested and then add the field

```
n(JsObject(Map.empty)) -> JsObject(Map("nested" -> JsObject("age" -> JsNumber(45)))
```

Comment: It would be nice if you also provide your definitions of `jsObject` and `jsNumber`

Comment: And `Index` instance

Comment: It looks like  trouble is in the implementation of `compose...` in Optional type. It handles via `modify` method. Which is dropping inner set if original is `None`

Comment: I've raised an [issue here](https://github.com/julien-truffaut/Monocle/issues/301)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

let's have a look at `index` and `at` signature for `JsObject`:

```
def at(field: String): Lens[JsObject, Option[Json]]
def index(field: String): Optional[JsObject, Json]
```

`at` is a `Lens` so its target ('Option[Json]') is always present. It means that we can `add`, `delete` and `update` the `Json` element at any field of a `JsonObject`.

```
import argonaut._, Argonaut._
import monocle.function._

(jObjectPrism composeLens at("name")).set(Some(jString("John")))(Json())
> res0: argonaut.Json = {"name":"John"}

(jObjectPrism composeLens at("name")).set(Some(jString("Robert")))(res0)
> res1: argonaut.Json = {"name":"Robert"}

(jObjectPrism composeLens at("name")).set(None)(res0)
> res2: argonaut.Json = {}
```

On the other hand, `index` is an `Optional` so it is target (`Json`) may or may not be there. It means that `index` can only `update` values but cannot `add` or `delete`.

```
(jObjectPrism composeLens index("name")).set(jString("Robert"))(Json())
> res3: argonaut.Json = {}

(jObjectPrism composeLens index("name")).set(jString("Robert"))(res0)
> res4: argonaut.Json = {"name":"Robert"}
```

So to come back to your original question, if you want to `add` or `update` value at a particular field, you need to use `at` and wrap the `Json` in a `Some` (see `res1`), it will overwrite or create the `Json` at that field.

Comment: So I ended up using the at (also has the functionality to remove the field when you set (None).  To maintain type-safety I just used a non-composed prism, .set(prism.reverseGet(_))

Answer (score 3):

At the moment there is very [specific behaviour](https://github.com/julien-truffaut/Monocle/blob/f6b163b1702bef046f26576d2e182f32352b88d7/core/src/main/scala/monocle/Optional.scala#L141) in the library.

When you composing `Optional` with some `Iso` or `Prism` it's downgrading right hand side argument to `POptional` and that's trouble.

`Iso[A,B]` and `Prism[A,B]` differs from `Lens[A,B]` and `Optional[A,B]` in sense that `reverseGet` can create element of `A` totally from `B` while `set` needs original value of `A`

So when for `Optional` and `Lens` it's totally legit that you can not modify part of the value, while not having this value in orignal `Map` or `JsObject`, for `Iso` and `Prism` you can define another behaviour.

And while waiting for [the issue](https://github.com/julien-truffaut/Monocle/issues/301) to be discussed, you can use following workaround

```
implicit class POptStrictComposition[S, T, A, B](self: POptional[S, T, A, B]) {
  def sComposePrism[C, D](other: PPrism[A, B, C, D]) = new POptional[S, T, C, D] {
    def getOrModify(s: S): T \/ C =
      self.getOrModify(s).flatMap(a => other.getOrModify(a).bimap(self.set(_)(s), identity))

    def set(d: D): S => T =
      self.set(other.reverseGet(d))

    def getOption(s: S): Option[C] =
      self.getOption(s) flatMap other.getOption

    def modifyF[F[_] : Applicative](f: C => F[D])(s: S): F[T] =
      self.modifyF(other.modifyF(f))(s)

    def modify(f: C => D): S => T =
      self.modify(other.modify(f))
  }

  def ^!<-?[C, D](o: PPrism[A, B, C, D]) = sComposePrism(o)

  def sComposeIso[C, D](other: PIso[A, B, C, D]) = sComposePrism(other.asPrism)

  def ^!<->[C, D](o: PIso[A, B, C, D]) = sComposeIso(o)
}
```

now you can try to change your code to

```
(jsObject composeOptional index("age") sComposePrism jsNumber).set(45)
```

and report if it helped

Comment: @JPullar Actually I'm strongly suggesting to accept Julien Truffaut's answer. Right after writing this answer I've read Jullien's explanation here and in issue and concluded that my approach is wrong.Accepting of this answer could lead to misunderstanding of library ideology.